# Filtering with conditions pandas df containing a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, filter, conditional-statements

I have a df which has list objects inside its cells:

```
data['country_code']
0       [IT, IT]
1       [PL, PL]
2       [IT, IT]
3       [IT, IT]
4       [IT, IT]
          ...   
6318    [XX, MT]
6319    [FI, FI]
6320    [XX, XX]
6321    [FI, FI]
6322    [FI, FI]
Name: country_code, Length: 6323, dtype: object
```

I would like to filter dataframe `data` if lists in `data['country_code']` has `'SK'` or `'CZ'`  as either first or second element

Something like this:

```
data[first element of data['country_code'] == 'SK'or'CZ' or second element of data['country_code'] == 'SK'or'CZ']
```

In MongoDB syntax it would be:

```
.find({$or: [{country_code: $elemMatch = 'SK'}, {country_code: $elemMatch = 'CZ'}]})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```py
print(df[df.country_code.apply(lambda x: "SK" in x or "CZ" in x)])
```

Prints:

```
  country_code
3     [IT, CZ]
4     [SK, IT]
```

---

`df` used:

```
  country_code
0     [IT, IT]
1     [PL, PL]
2     [IT, IT]
3     [IT, CZ]
4     [SK, IT]
```

Comment: works, ty! will accept it in 5 mins. BTW it felt like a little bit chicken coding. However it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `pd.Series.str` accessor:

```
l = ['SK', 'CZ']

print (data[data['country_code'].str[0].isin(l)|data["country"].str[1].isin(l)])
```